# Tool already edits when using shortcut keys

Tags: modeling

I'm sure this must have been thought out, but I find this behaviour really off-putting...so, let's use bevel as an example. In the supplied gif, I am first activating the bevel tool using the ctrl+B shortcut, but this *immediately* makes the tool active. It doesn't wait for me to press the mouse down. 
Yet, when I activate the same tool via the menu, as you can see in the gif, it waits for me to click.

Why is there this different behaviour between two ways of activating the same tool? If I want to use the shortcut key, I have to put up with a tool working in a way that I do not want?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the shortcuts, that is always how blender worked. Since clicking on the tools on the left is just switching the mode, or what will happen when you click/drag (look at the select tool, then switch to the 3D cursor tool), you have to activate it to work. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm really used to keeping a tool active. So, for example, I would click and drag to make a bevel, release the mouse, then push the mouse down again to tweak _the same_ bevel operation. Is that not possible in Blender?

Comment: To some degree. if you bevel the edges a bit, then click/drag again, it can only bevel it more, not less from where it was last. Does that help?

Comment: On the second click it will apply another bevel, not adjust the first. I'm talking very generally about how the tools behave, not just about the bevel tool specifically. It's a shame as I was considering Blender as a modelling package, but I'll have to see if my brain will ever get used to working this way.

Comment: @Corbormite I noticed that if you hit Shift+Space, then Ctrl+B, you will switch to the bevel tool without it yet being active. This implies there must be a way to use keys to do the same. I may be wrong of course.

Comment: That's funny Anti-Distinctlyminty. When i answered your first comment that wasn't the case. I'm not sure what changed since yesterday. But as for your latest comment, I think Shift+Space, then Ctrl+B is the quickest way to switch without your mouse clicking the tool.